# How do I plot geom_tiles in ggmap using a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to plot this data on a ggmap over Toronto Ontario. However, all I get is an accurate legend and a blank map with the stamen map. It's

Here's my data: [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gq0ynAKO_v06sf8MUXD9_JHgI0fHHfJs/view?usp=share_link)

It looks like this

```
head(test)
           final Month_Yr         X        Y
2575548 5.699134  2018-12 -79.83759 43.28888
2575550 0.000000  2018-12 -79.58547 43.89921
2575552 0.000000  2018-12 -79.69059 43.87526
2575554 5.111695  2018-12 -79.88913 43.30200
2575555 2.818152  2018-12 -79.34186 43.65824
2575556 5.667874  2018-12 -79.83636 43.28887
```

Here's my workflow:

```
library(data.table)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(terra)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library("ggmap")


library(RColorBrewer)
# library(brewerpal)
library(colorRamps)
library(colorspace)

# open libraries
library(tidyverse)

gtha <- c(left = -79.95306, bottom = 43.27577, right = -78.91296, top = 43.95626 )

get_stamenmap(gtha, maptype = "toner-lite",crop = FALSE) %>% ggmap() +
  geom_tile(data = test , aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = final)) +
  theme_void()
```

This is what I end up with:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I want to end up with a raster-link image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are plotting on continuous scales. Hence the tiles are simply to (infinitesimally) small to be visible.

To make the tiles visible set the `width` and `height` or use `geom_point` with a rectangle shape instead.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
#> ℹ Google's Terms of Service: <https://mapsplatform.google.com>
#> ℹ Please cite ggmap if you use it! Use `citation("ggmap")` for details.

gtha <- c(left = -79.95306, bottom = 43.27577, right = -78.91296, top = 43.95626)

map <- get_stamenmap(gtha, maptype = "toner-lite", crop = FALSE)
#> ℹ Map tiles by Stamen Design, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL.

p <- ggmap(map) +
  theme_void()

p +
  geom_tile(data = test, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = final), height = .1, width = .1)
```

[image]

```r
p +
  geom_point(data = test, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = final), shape = 22)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
test <- structure(list(final = c(
  5.699134, 0, 0, 5.111695, 2.818152,
  5.667874
), Month_Yr = c(
  "2018-12", "2018-12", "2018-12", "2018-12",
  "2018-12", "2018-12"
), X = c(
  -79.83759, -79.58547, -79.69059,
  -79.88913, -79.34186, -79.83636
), Y = c(
  43.28888, 43.89921, 43.87526,
  43.302, 43.65824, 43.28887
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "2575548",
  "2575550", "2575552", "2575554", "2575555", "2575556"
))
```

Comment: I tried this, and the issues actually seems to be the fact that I converted a regular grid from a 2D XY plane into a WGS lat/long plane, so the points are all over the place when they should be a regular grid. How do I fix this in ggmap?